# Using Identity in an ASP Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on a project which has a web solution using .NET 7 and an API solution using .NET 6.

Basically I have the identity code in the API and the session cookie is being set correctly on the users browser.  But when I try and hit an endpoint with the Authorize attribute, it throws an error.

I'm not sure if identity can be used this way so any help is appreciated.

Only the API has access to the database so the identity implementation has been done there.  When the user logs in a post is sent to the API which then uses the SignInAsync method in the SignInManager to log the user in.  Once the user logs in successfully the .AspNetCore.Session cookie is set on the browser.

Some of the controllers in the API have the Authorize attribute which is in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization namespace.  However when I try and post to these controllers it doesn't work.  I get a 500 error in the response.  If I add the AllowAnonymous attribute they do work.

I've had a look online but can't see much about this problem.  Most tutorials suggest to use a JWT but that might be a bit over the top for this project.  Should this approach work and if so is there anything I can try to get it working?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the details 500 error message when you get inside the response?